# "libnnz19.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: python, cx-oracle, instantclient

I have installed cx_oracle(python3) and instant client 21_1 inside a container. When I try to first time I got this error

```
Cannot locate a 64-bit Oracle Client library: "/python- 
env/instantclient_21_1/lib/libclntsh.so:
```

So I have created lib under /python-env/instantclient_21_1/ and tried again, now I'm getting this error

> cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: DPI-1047: Cannot locate a 64-bit Oracle Client library: "libnnz19.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory". See https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/installation.html for help

I don't understand where is it searching for the that so file. It is already present in /python-
env/instantclient_21_1/lib/

Please help

Comment: Is that location in `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`? Does running `ldd` against the library (to see what other libraries it depends on in turn) give you another error that would point to root cause?

Comment: Running ldd return all the list, it seems all dependencies resolved

Comment: That's encouraging. And does setting `LDD_LIBRARY_PATH` to include the directory (`export LDD_LIBRARY_PATH=/python-env/instantclient_21_1/lib`) change anything?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Update: use the latest version of cx_Oracle, which was renamed python-oracledb. See the [release announcement](https://cjones-oracle.medium.com/open-source-python-thin-driver-for-oracle-database-e82aac7ecf5a)]

Follow the [Instant Client installation steps](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/lacli/install-instant-client-using-zip.html#GUID-D3DCB4FB-D3CA-4C25-BE48-3A1FB5A22E84) or [cx_Oracle Installation steps](https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/installation.html#oracle-instant-client-zip-files) and use `ldconfig` to set the library path to include the Instant Client directory.

You could set `DPI_DEBUG_LEVEL=64` (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67030388/libclntsh-so-cannot-open-shared-object-file-no-such-file-or-directory-centos-8)) to trace how cx_Oracle is looking for the libraries.

Also see [Docker for Oracle Database Applications in Node.js and Python](https://blogs.oracle.com/opal/docker-for-oracle-database-applications-in-nodejs-and-python-part-1).